# Selenium driver.getTitle() is not working

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

driver.getTitle() does not return the title of the page. It returns null. I have the below html structure in the web page:

```
<head>
  <!-- needed for translation of titles -->

  <!-- needed for gomez.jsp -->
  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js"> </script><script type="text/javascript"> … </script><script src="https://B001E0.t.axf8.net/js/gtag5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>
     Applications
  </title>
  so on....
```

Could somebody explain whats the problem here.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Then you might want to put explicit waits like below:

```
    void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
        ExpectedCondition pageLoads = new
            ExpectedCondition() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return (Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
                }
            };
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(pageLoads);
    }
```

And then you can perform below action:

```
    driver.getTitle()
```

Comment: I think your WebApplication is not opened when driver.getTitle() have executed. so you need to put explicit or implicit waits to wait till your page is loaded sucessfully.

Comment: is your webpage loaded successfully or was it in progress?

Comment: No its loaded successfully.

Comment: I've modified my answer, check it out.

Comment: Paras, Sorry i was out from office could not reply you yesterday. The above code is giving lot of errors in my eclipse. Have you ever used this code successfully??

Comment: void is an invalid type for the variable waitForLoad

Comment: - The type new ExpectedCondition(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Function.apply(Object).

Comment: Try now, I've forgot to cast it to Boolean as this method returns boolean value. try now.

Comment: yes I've changed it.. I've typecasted the code with (Boolean) when I am returning the value.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be late for you but I am just putting it so that other can get the help.
1st lame way is that you can just add

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
//(2000 is the time in milliseconds) before the the 
driver.getTitle();
```

You can give the time what every you want, what it will do is just slow down your execution time for 2 seconds (in this case)

2nd you can use

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebD`enter code here`riverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue("complete"));
driver.getTitle();
```

It will only work if your HTML and JS returns the text complete
now you will get the new pages title and you can use it for verification.

adding one more code to the thread:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        try{
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(eTitle));
            Reporter.log("PASS: Title is matching.", true);
        }
```

Comment: Yeah. This is pretty old. I solved iut long back. Thanks anyway. WebDriverWait is a better way always.