# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at newproject.PG1.main(PG1.java:30)

Tags: java

How do I fix this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at newproject.PG1.main(PG1.java:30), I believe it is about the the getTitle method, but I don't know how to correct it.

```
My code is below

package newproject;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//comment the above line and uncomment below line to use Chrome
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class PG1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //comment the above 2 lines and uncomment below 2 lines to use Chrome
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\chromedriver.exe");
        //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/newtours/";
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
        String actualTitle = "";

        // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        // get the actual value of the title
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

        /*
         * compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and print
         * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
         */
        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }

        //close Fire fox
        driver.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is line 30?

Comment: IF it's by driver.getTitle(), you might want to check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631387/selenium-driver-gettitle-is-not-working

Comment: Could you write full stackTrace please?

Answer (score 1):

`actualTitle` is null - Try to opposite the if statement part, instead of `actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)` do `expectedTitle.contentEquals(actualTitle)`, this will not produce a NPE.

Comment: I will be happy to hear other explanations..

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  It's almost definitely the correct answer to the question as asked.